# jqgrid with cakephp --- Call to a member function url() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my controller,

```
<?php
    class PostsController extends AppController
    {
        var $name='Posts';
        var $helpers=array('Html','Form');
        var $components = array('Session','Paginator');




        function beforeFilter()
        {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            // $this->Auth->allow('index');  
        }

        function index()
        {

        }

        function getsites()
        {
            $this->layout= false;
            $this->autoRender=false;

            configure::write('debug',0);

            // get no of rows
            $limit= $this->params['url']['rows'];

            //get the index row for sorting
            $sidx= $this->params['url']['sidx'];

            //get the sort order
            $sord= $this->params['url']['sord'];

            $page= $this->params['url']['page'];

            //if sort collumn index not found then set it to 1
            if(empty($sidx)) $sidx=1;

            //calculate no of rows from query
            $row=$this->Post->find('count');
            $count=$row;

            //if count is >0 then set total no of pages as per give limit
            //else set total pages to 0
            if($count>0)
                $total_pages=ceil($count/$limit);
            else
                $total_pages=0;

            //set start position of records
            $start=$limit*$page-$limit;

            if($start<0) $start=0;

            //set range for data from database
            $limitRange=$start.",".$limit;
            $sortRange=$sidx.",".$sord;

            //fetch only pure data avoiding unnecessay loading of related/associated data
            $this->Post->recursive=-1;
            $result=$this->Post->find('all',array('fields'=>array('id','title'),'order'=>$sortRange,'limit'=>$limitRange));

            //setting the response object
            $i=0;
            $response->page=$page;
            $response->total_pages=$total_pages;
            $response->records=$count;

            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row['Post']['id'];
                $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['Post']['id'],$row['Post']['title'],$row['Post']['id']);

                $i++;
            }

            echo json_encode($response);

            exit;

        }
}

this is the index.ctp

<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /* #id === id of the table */
        $("#list").jqGid({
            url:'<?php echo $html->url(array("controller"=>"Posts","action"=>"getsites")); ?>',
            datatype:"json",
            colNames:['Id','Title','IdHidden','Edit'],
            colModel:[
                        {name:'id',index:'id',width:10},
                        {name:'title',index:'title',width:90},
                        {name:'idHidden',index:'idHidden',width:10,hidden:true},
                        {name:'Edit',index:'Edit',width:10,formatter : function(cellvalue,options,rowObject){return '<span class="editButtonSite ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" title="click to edit"></span>';}},
                    ],
            rowNum:2,
            rowList:[2,4,6],
            pager:jQuery("#pager"),
            caption:'View Posts',
            sortname:'id',
            sortorder:'asc',
            autowidth:true,
            viewrecords:true,
            loadcomplete:function(){
                $("#content table tr td .editButtonSite").click(function(){
                /*var ids = $(this).parent().prev().attr('title');
                var editPage = '<?php echo $html->url(array("controller" => "sites", "action" => "edit"))?>';
                editPage = editPage + "/" + ids;
                window.location.href = editPage;*/
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<table id="list" style="height:auto;"></table>
<div id="pager" style="height:auto;"></div>
```

default.ctp goes here

```
 <?php
        echo $this->Html->css('ui.jqgrid');
        echo $this->fetch('css');

        echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.jqgrid');

?>
```

The above is my code for using jqgrid in cake 2.x

I'm getting the following error....

Fatal Error

```
  Error: Call to a member function url() on a non-object
  File: /var/www/html/jqgridtry.local/app/View/Posts/index.ctp  Line: 6
```

help me get out of this..

Answer (score 0):

correct your code using Cake 2.x HtmlHelper .

```
url:'<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("controller"=>"Posts","action"=>"getsites")); ?>',
```

Answer (score 0):

On /app/View/Posts/index.ctp file line 6, you shouldn't use `$html->url`, instead use this `Router::url` for better understand ind, please see this link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html